# Why private variable in a class is treated as public in the transpiled code

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5, typescript2.0, tsc

I have added following class in typescript

```
class Person {
    private variable1;
    public varibele2;

    Person(){
        this.variable1 = 'abc';
        this.varibele2 = 'xyz'; 
    }

    public getVariable1(){
        return this.variable1;        
    }
}
```

So When I compile the code using tsc , it generates the following code

```
var Person =  (function () {
    function Person() {
    }
    Person.prototype.Person = function () {
        this.variable1 = 'abc';
        this.varibele2 = 'xyz';
    };
    Person.prototype.getVariable1 = function () {
        return this.variable1;
    };
    return Person;
}());
```

Since variable1 is private should not be accessible by the obj of that class(which is happening in typescript code).

Same behavior should be happened  into transpiled es5 code(But not happening).

In above example's transpiled code I am creating object of the Person

```
var p = new Person();
console.log(p.variable1); // undefined 
p.variable1 = 'abc1';  // setting value to variable 1 
console.log(p.variable1); // 'abc1'
console.log(p.getVariable1()); // 'abc1'
```

In above code I should not be able to set or get the value of variable1.

```
var p = new Person();
console.log(p.getVariable1()); // 'undefined' 
p.variable1 = 'abc1';  // setting value to variable1 
console.log(p.getVariable1()); // 'abc1'
```

In above code , I am trying fetch the value using p.getVariable1() and I get undefined.Since value is already assigned in constructor of the class , it should be available through  p.getVariable1()

```
var p = new Person();
console.log(p.variable2); // undefined
p.variable2 = 'xyz1'; // setting value
console.log(p.variable2);// 'xyz1'
```

In above code Variable2 should retrun 'xyz' but it's not. Once i assign value to it , it returns.

So Behavior of private and public variables are same in transpiled code and its very confusing.
Its not returning the value which is assigned in constructor.

Comment: Javascript does not have private variables. Typescript's private variables are only checked at compile time, which is useful for development, but doesn't provide protections at runtime.

Comment: I understand that javascript doesn't provide access modifier(protection or data hiding) concept but there is a way to achieve data hiding using closure, but here compiled code is not implementing proper closure  for making variables public and private.

Comment: Yes, closures can make variables private-ish, but that's not what typescript's goal is. Typescript provides compile time checking, and nothing else.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need the checks at runtime? Is it not enough that the IDE or build process tells you there's an type error when you try to access `p.variable1`?

Comment: I am thinking about what browser understand , it understand compiled javascript , if compiled javascript doesn't following the same concept then whats the use of making variable private and public at compile time.

Comment: `whats the use of making variable private and public at compile time.` The use is that typescript will tell you you have a problem with your code (ie, you're accessing something private). Then you change your code so that you're no longer doing that.

Comment: But in reality its not private, data hiding should not be performed at IDE . it should be performed at run time.We do protection from end user .

Comment: Correct. In reality, it's not private. That's not what typescript is for.

Answer (score 3):

To continue our discussion from the comments, here's the benefit that you get from using public vs private:

[image: example of typescript errors]

The IDE will tell you immediately that you're doing something you're not supposed to do. If you ignore these errors, the code will compile to javascript and run, but the point is that you **don't** ignore these errors. When you write bad code like this, typescript tells you there's a problem, and then you can fix the problem. If you have a build process, you can set it up so that these typescript errors will fail the build, thus forcing you to fix the problem before deploying.

Typescript is a tool to help you write better javascript code, by catching errors earlier and easier. It is not a tool to change the way javascript works. Typescript does not provide runtime type checking, and if that's what you're after, you won't find it. If you need closures to hide variables, then create a closure yourself.

Comment: Still my question is " why the concept of public and private variable in typescript if runtime everything is public ? " .Why can't have only default public concept in typescript then ?

Comment: To catch bugs earlier and easier.

Comment: can you explain How can we catch bugs by making variables private and public ?

Comment: In the screenshot that i just posted, the red underlines are pointing out two bugs.

Comment: you didn't understand my question . Can't I catch bug if i don't have the concept of access modifier ? you are saying specific to IDE.  ok tell me whats the use of access modifier i general ?

Comment: I'm running out of ways to say this. Typescript lets you describe that you want something to be private. Then if you write code that accesses something it shouldn't access, typescript tells you you have a bug. So then you change your code so that you don't have the bug. After you've fixed the bug, you are never accessing a private variable. Since you never access it, it's a moot issue whether or not it's checked at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

First, to respond to your main question:

> Why private variable in a class is treated as public in the transpiled code.

It's true that `private` properties, as well as `readonly` properties, are transpiled into plain properties hence "public". I think it's to simplify and boost transpilation TS→JS and to favor using TypeScript everywhere, where warnings or errors are emitted when performing invalid operations on these kind of properties: accessing a private property outside the class, reassigning a readonly property...

But you give examples with very strange behaviors. They are not due to TypeScript transpilation. I notice some issues with your class Person that have led to them:

- In ES6 and TypeScript, the class constructor is defined using the keyword `constructor`, not the class name. It's even more confusing because the constructor is transpiled into a function constructor named like the class, here `Person`.
- There's a typo with the second property: `varibele2` instead of `variable2`. This is why `console.log(p.variable2)` can't print the expected value.

Fixing these issues, the code behaves more logically.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(private _variable1 = 'abc', public variable2 = 'xyz') { }

    public get variable1() { return this._variable1; }
}

console.log(new Person()); // → Person { v1: [Getter], v2: "xyz", _v1: "abc", __proto__... }
```

The transpiled code is available through the [TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20_v1%20%3D%20'abc'%2C%20public%20v2%20%3D%20'xyz')%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20v1()%20%7B%20return%20this._v1%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(new%20Person())%3B%0D%0A).

*Note*: I favor another syntax:

- Properties are declared directly in the constructor: it's more compact, it enables type inference and we can specify other initial values.
- Private variable are named `_x` to ease writing a getter `get x() { return this._x; }`. It's also a commonly used JavaScript convention to indicate that the variable is meant to be private, without a complex pattern to really have a private property.

Answer (score 1):

if the transpiled code is not using closure to make it private it means I can flout the variables when using it as a javascript library because I will never know what is private what is not. So the answer is transpiling the way typescript does is incorrect and not in true spirit of usage of javascript.

Comment: Not honoring typescript private into transpiled Js using closure function means some method in another js can change the value of our variable if it wants without having.

Answer (score 0):

In following case as per my understanding, variable2 comes undefined because object p don't contain that variable.

In following code we are including variable using p.variable2 = 'xyz1' into object p. so in the third line we get the value of that variable.

```
var p = new Person();
console.log(p.variable2); // undefined
p.variable2 = 'xyz1'; // setting value
console.log(p.variable2);// 'xyz1'
```

Still the question is since typescript has declared the variable then why javascript(compiled code)  object doesn't contain those variables?